# Sand caked in his eyes

Tags: meaning

I can't understand this sentence "My pet had some sand caked in his eyes."
I know this is a bad situation in his eyes, but not exactly understood.
Could you tell me what the "sand caked" is?
It it possible this is the wrong spelling or something.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at the dictionary meanings for “cake” (as a verb) and tried to related them to sand?

Comment: Oh! Sand is a verb! Sorry, I believed it was noun...

Comment: Now I can understand what it means. Thank you so much.

Comment: No, _sand_ is not a verb, but _cake_ is (here). Wet sand sticks together.

Comment: I went looking for images of "sand caked eyes" and got hundreds of makeup pictures. Then I tried "crusty eyes" and nearly lost my breakfast. Ick! Don't Google *that*.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the comments have already conveyed all the information you need, but in the interest of having the answer present in the "answers" section:

One of the meanings of "cake" is as a verb referring to a fluid which hardens to become encrusted, particularly as a result of drying or if it covers another object. Examples of the phenomenon are wet sand drying or cement curing. "Caked" here is simply the past tense of the verb. Some other examples of the word are "His boots were caked with mud" (covered in the dried mud) or "due to imperfect seals, moisture was able to enter the cans and cause the powder therein to cake."